# "the way" vs "in the way"

Tags: prepositions, adverbial-phrases

> They don't write songs the way they used to.
>
> It's amazing the way she manages to stay calm.
>
> The way he was yelling, you'd have thought he was badly hurt.
>
> I love you the way you are.

These are examples, I found, of the use of "the way".

I was using "in the way" *in that way* "the way" is used there.
But the thing is,

people say, for the last sentence of examples, I can't use "in the way" in place of "the way". That means natives never use "I love you in the way you are" and I'm more confused as thinking the first one is okay with the use of "in the way" instead.

so,

What is the exact difference between "the way" and "in the way"?
and

Which case those two are un-interchangeable?

Comment: “`the ... way`” as an adverbial clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that "way" has a large number of meanings.

In the first sentence (which *by the way* is the only one where I could use "in the way" though it tugs at my ears) you have

> 4
>   a :  manner or method of doing or happening < admired her way of thinking>;
>
> also :  method of accomplishing :  means < that's the way to do it>

The second sentence uses the same meaning but in a different way. Changing it around to

> The way she manages to stay calm is amazing.

Shows you exactly why you couldn't have "in the way" there. Really it just takes the meaning "how" I can't find that exact meaning in the Merriam-Webster but I would say it really boils down to "method of accomplishing".

The third sentence uses "the way" idiomatically the M-W has the following explanation and example

> - the way
>
>   1
>     :  in view of the manner in which < you'd think she was rich, the way she spends money>

The last version uses a different meaning again

> 9 :  state of affairs :  condition, state

The only case of these where you can use "in the way" is when you are using way as a synonym for "manner" or "method".

"in the way" has many more possible meanings derived from the meanings of "way".

As examples consider

> We couldn't move further; the blockade was in the way.

Meaning it was obstructing further progress.

> She's is in the family way.

Meaning she is pregnant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then do you mean where "in the way" is used, "the way" is always allowed to be used?

Comment: No. For example when something is in the way (i.e. is an obstruction) you must use in. If you are using in the sense of manner or method though, you can usually drop the "in" I think. I certainly can't come up with a counter example.